# Kial estas "malvarm" en "malvarmumo"?

Tags: etymology

Malvarmumo estas malsano kaŭzita de viruso. Se oni pecetigas la vorton, oni povas vidi "malvarm" kaj "umo". Kiel tiu malsano rilatas al malvarmeco?

Comment: Ĉu aserto estas vera ofte dependas de kiun lingvon – la ordinaran aŭ la teĥnikan – vi uzas. Ekzemple, en la ordinara lingvo ‘blanka’ estas koloro, sed en la teĥnika lingvo, ne. Kaj la ordinara lingvo ankoraŭ parolas pri ‘sun-leviĝo’, kio estas tute fremda por la teĥnika lingvo. Ne distingi inter la ordinara lingvo kaj la teĥnika lingvo kondukas al senfina serio da enigmoj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ĝi estas el aliaj lingvoj, ekzemple la angla por "malvarmumo" estas *cold*, la sama vorto kiel la vorto por "malvarmo"; ili kredis ke sidi en malvarma loko kaŭzas malvarmumojn.

Comment: Ankaŭ ŝajne en la hispana, germana kaj itala la vorto por malvarmumo rilatas al malvarmo. Eble ĝi ne vere devenas rekte de la angla sed estis simple ĝenerale akceptita ideo ke malvarmumo rilatas al la malvarmo.

Comment: Vere, mi redaktis laŭe ĝin.